# Rails 5: Letsencrypt with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, heroku, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to figure out how to add lets encrypt SSL to my Rails 5 app on heroku.

I'm trying to use gem 'letsencrypt_plugin'

I'm getting stuck on Step 3 of these instructions: https://github.com/lgromanowski/letsencrypt-plugin/wiki/Installation-guide

When I try to rake db:migrate, I get an error that says:

```
rake aborted!
Psych::SyntaxError: (/Users/ooo/config/letsencrypt_plugin.yml): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 2 column 3
```

Line 2 of my config/letsencrypt_plugin.yml has:

```
endpoint: 'https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/'
```

I don't know if this setting is a template, that I'm supposed to change to something specific to my app (if it is, then what should it be changed to???).

Can anyone see what's going wrong?

This is a different problem to the identified duplicate. The problem specifically identifies an issue with the installation guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 5, Heroku with Let's Encrypt SSL - trouble getting setup configured](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907302/rails-5-heroku-with-lets-encrypt-ssl-trouble-getting-setup-configured)

Answer (score 1):

For others using the same gem, the issue is that the template set out in the installation docs using single ' quotation marks for the inner and outer content. You need to switch the outer quotation marks for double " quotation marks.

Comment: The documentation was fixed on [Oct 12, 2016](https://github.com/lgromanowski/letsencrypt-plugin/wiki/Installation-guide/_compare/9fc8d63550c216004ce26aa9454fb03157de4963...8df4f339829a4b4701a47b822190afe80d384762)